# D3.js - Why are all my data being appended to the last appended group?

Tags: d3.js

I'm pretty new to D3.js, and I've been able to create a simple animation that suits my needs from the [Health and Wealth of Nations](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/) example. I had some trouble with adding labels to SVG circles, and when I investigated the source I found that while a group is being appended for each object in my dataset, all of the circles are being added to the last group only.

JSON data:

```
{"numSegments":4,
"movement":[
    {"Id":"1",
    "xValues":[[0,350],[1,400],[2,350],[3,300],[4,350]],
    "yValues":[[0,690],[1,640],[2,590],[3,640],[4,690]]},
    {"Id":"2",
    "xValues":[[0,150],[1,150],[2,150],[3,150], [4, 150]],
    "yValues":[[0,690],[1,490],[2,690],[3,490],[4, 690]]},
    {"Id":"3",
    "xValues":[[0,550],[1,650],[2,550],[3,650],[4,550]],
    "yValues":[[0,690],[1,590],[2,490],[3,390],[4,490]]},
    {"Id":"4",
    "xValues":[[0,0],[1,200],[2,0],[3,200],[4,0]],
    "yValues":[[0,0],[1,200],[2,0],[3,200],[4,0]]}
    ]
}
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)

var g = chart.append("g")
            .selectAll(".node")
            .data(interpolateData(0));

var sections = g.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node");

console.log(sections.size()); // this returns "4" as expected

var dot = sections.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return colour(key(d)); })
    .attr("r", "10")
    .call(position)
    .sort(order);

dot.append("title")
    .text(function (d) { return key(d); });

var text = sections.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return key(d); })
    .call(positionText)
    .sort(order);
```

SVG output:

```
<svg class="chart" width="700" height="700">
<g>
    <g class="node"></g>
    <g class="node"></g>
    <g class="node"></g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle class="dot" fill="#fff" r="10">
            <title>1</title>
        </circle>
        <circle class="dot" fill="#fff" r="10">
            <title>2</title>
        </circle>
        <circle class="dot" fill="#fff" r="10">
            <title>3</title>
        </circle>
        <circle class="dot" fill="#fff" r="10">
            <title>4</title>
        </circle>
        <text>1</text>
        <text>2</text>
        <text>3</text>
        <text>4</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

If the size of **sections** is 4 as the console reports, is it not an array of the four `<g>` elements that were just appended? And if so, why does **sections.append()** add four elements to the last group instead of adding one element to each of the four groups?

Comment: What does `positionText()` do?

Comment: It sets the x and y coordinates of the `<text>` elements:

    `function positionText(text) {
                text.attr("dx", function (d) { return xScale(x(d)) - 7.5; })
                    .attr("dy", function (d) { return yScale(y(d)) + 5; })`

xScale() and yScale() scale the coordinates to the chart boundaries.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error https://jsfiddle.net/tp4qr1ot/

Comment: Your code snippet worked fine in my development environment, so I started adding elements of my program until I found the culprit. It looks like the `.sort(order)` function was the source of the problem, if I remove that from the append() statement (and the transition that followed) everything looks as expected. I had copied the function as it was used in the Wealth and Health of Nations example: `function order(a, b) {
                return a.id - b.id;
            }`

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a bug in D3 to me.